# send_keys does not working in django testing

Tags: python, django, selenium, testing

I want functional testing

functional test process is

1. Create_user
2. log in the website using created user
3. click a button named `booksale`

**In `myproject/functional_test/test_booksale.py`**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase

from users.models import User


class OurClientLogInTest(LiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        ## create 1 user id
        User.objects.create_user(username='MyTestID', password='123', nickname='NICKNAMETEST', phone='01011111111')


    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_our_client_can_log_in_this_website(self):

        # url connect
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)

        # web page header title has 'Korea book'
        self.assertIn('Korea book', self.browser.title)

        # click log_in button in main page
        log_in = self.browser.find_element_by_id('log_in')
        log_in.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        self.assertIn('로그인', self.browser.title)

        # insert username, password
        # click enter
        username_box = self.browser.find_element_by_name('username')
        password_box = self.browser.find_element_by_name('password')

        username_box.send_keys('MyTestID')
        password_box.send_keys('123')

        self.browser.find_element_by_id('button').click()

        ##redirect main page
        self.assertIn('Korea book', self.browser.title)

        ## click a button named book_sale
        book_sale = self.browser.find_element_by_id('book_sale')
        book_sale.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        from IPython import embed; embed()
```

I command `python manage.py functional_test`

it show me error

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/study_alone/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1198, in __call__
return super(FSFilesHandler, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/study_alone/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 177, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/study_alone/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1181, in get_response
return self.serve(request)
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/study_alone/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1193, in serve
return serve(request, final_rel_path, document_root=self.get_base_dir())
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/study_alone/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/static.py", line 54, in serve
fullpath = os.path.join(document_root, newpath)
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/posixpath.py", line 89, in join
genericpath._check_arg_types('join', a, *p)
  File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/genericpath.py", line 143, in _check_arg_types
(funcname, s.__class__.__name__)) from None
TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'NoneType'
```

when I remove the code

```
book_sale.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

the test passed very clearly

I can't not understand why book_sale button doesn't send ENTER KEY..

please some body help me

Comment: the error is not in this code, but in what happens when the form is submitted

Comment: if `book_sale` is button why are you not using `book_sale.click()` instead of `send_keys()`??

Comment: @e4c5 ummm,,,, I can't under stand about your comment `but in what happens when the form is submitted`... could you tell me a advice easier please?

Comment: Clicking submit or hitting enter on a form usually results in the form being submitted. This stacktrae does not show any lines from your test code or anything related to that. It must be caused by the form submit

Comment: @SaurabhGaur oh my god.... I tried `click` method already... but I'm not insert braket.... thank you!!

Comment: @e4c5 I'm so glad about your kind! Thanks for the good information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `book_sale` element is button, you should try using [`.click()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.click) instead of [`send_keys()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.send_keys) as :-

```
book_sale.click()
```

Comment: Thank you @Saurahb Gaur I solved my problem using your solution!

Comment: @MinHan You welcom, As I'm seeing in your provided code, you are using every where `.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` to perform click, need to replace it by `.click()` as well..:)